# Boost log crashes with a simple example (Linux)

Tags: boost, boost-log

Ok, I know, this question sounds similar to other questions (none of them had been answered), but I cannot figure out why is failing. The simplest example possible is this:

```cpp
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main() {
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "hello world\n";
}
```

Of course, to compile this we need boost as a dependency, for this I decided to use [Conan](https://conan.io/) and this is the conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
boost/1.75.0

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

And, well, a simple CMake to build it all:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(concurrency)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS log)

add_executable(concurrency main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(concurrency Boost::log)
```

This builds without problems in Windows, macOS and Linux (tested in Fedora 33 and Ubuntu rolling). If I run the simple log in Windows and macOS, it works without any problems at all, but in Linux it fails with segmentation fault (run in Fedora 33):

```
Reading symbols from concurrency...
(No debugging symbols found in concurrency)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/build/concurrency
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.32-4.fc33.x86_64
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f1aa97896a2 in __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install libgcc-10.2.1-9.fc33.x86_64 libstdc++-10.2.1-9.fc33.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f1aa97896a2 in __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f1aa9a92ce0 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x000000000040ee81 in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::basic_ostringstreambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long) ()
#3  0x000000000040ed15 in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write(char const*, long) ()
#4  0x000000000040eaee in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator<<(char const*) ()
#5  0x000000000040e853 in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_record_ostream<char>::operator<<(char const*) ()
#6  0x000000000040e455 in main ()
```

Any idea what could be happening? I already tried including `Boost::log_setup` but same segfault is there.

Comment: I suspect, your Boost libraries might have been built with a different C++ standard library than the code you're compiling (i.e. libc++ from clang vs libstdc++ from gcc). Check symbol names referenced by Boost binaries and your binaries. `__cxx11` in namespace names indicate libstdc++, `__1` indicates libc++. Also, try compiling against Boost supplied in your Linux distro packages.

Comment: That is actually a good hint @AndreySemashev, I will change the parameters and update the question if the problem persist, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AndreySemashev suggestion helped me to find the issue. Apparently it is related to GCC ABI compatibility and versioning of the standard library.

[Conan documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html) covers the issue pretty well (and how to solve it). So for my previous example the only thing I have to do is setting the standard lib in Linux at install time:

```
conan install .. -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
```

Apparently, Conan assumes the old standard library for GCC 5 (the default version set for Boost).

I hope this helps someone else in the future.